# Modify HTML5 animation

Tags: html, html5-canvas

How can I set the starting point of this `HTML5` animation?

Basically I like to start the cycle production 100px from the button of the screen.

I'm a beginner with `html5 canvas`. 
Maybe there is an easy solution for this.

Any help is highly appreciated!

```js
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

var c = document.getElementById('canv'),
    $ = c.getContext('2d');

    c.width = window.innerWidth;
    c.height = window.innerHeight;

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    c.width = window.innerWidth;
    c.height = window.innerHeight;
}, false);

var arr = [];

var go = function() {
  $.fillStyle = "hsla(0,0%,10%,.8)";
  $.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  
  var p = new Part(c.width/2 , c.height);
  p.vx = Math.random() * 10-5;
  arr.push(p);

  for (var i in arr) {
    var p = arr[i];
    p.disp($);
    p.upd();
  }

  if (arr.length > 500) {
    arr.shift();
  }
}

var rnd = function(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

var Part = function(px, py) {
  this.px = px;
  this.py = py;
  this.vy = rnd(1.1, 2)*-8*1.1;
  this.vx = rnd(1.1, 2)*5*1.1;
  
  this.grav = 0.1;
  this.col = 0;
  this.rad = rnd(5,30);
  this.disp = function($) {
    $.fillStyle = "hsla(" + this.col + ", 95%, 60%, .8)";
    $.beginPath();
    $.arc(this.px, this.py, this.rad, 0, Math.PI*2);
    $.fill();
  }
    
    this.upd = function() {
      this.vy += this.grav;
      this.py += this.vy*1.1;
      this.px += this.vx* 1.1;
      this.col += 2;
  }
}

var run = function() {
  window.requestAnimFrame(run);
  go();

}
run();
```

```css
body{
  width:100%; 
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:hsla(0,0%,10%,1);
}
```

```html
<canvas id = 'canv'></canvas>
```

Comment: I think You can use this jquery plugin: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the animation to start 100px from bottom and then move down, or stay at 100px from bottom?

Inside of your `go` function, you can see `c.width` and `c.height` are both taken from the H and W of the window. These are then used for the `fillRect` (the background) and in the `p` variable. `p` includes `new Part`, which must mean particle! This must be where we have to play with `c.height`. So the easiest way to move the animation up from the bottom is just to subtract 100 from `c.height`, which means that the animation height is now the window height minus 100 pixels. This makes `var p = new Part(c.width/2 , c.height-100);`, and it looks like it does what you want.